# How to test if request.url matches a specific value

Tags: python, django

I am using django, jinja2 and flask.

I have the following URL format in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^gigs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$", 'gig.views.event_detail', name="event_detail"),
    url(r"^gigs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/basket/$", 'gig.views.event_basket', name="event_basket")
)
```

In my template I use `{% url 'event_detail' pk=event.id %}` to produce the URL for the first page.

How can I write a conditional statement to test if the current URL is this first page? Something like:

```
{% if request.url = url 'event_music' pk=event.id %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using flask and jinja2? Looks more like purely a django question to me...

Comment: You're gonna want to use `request.path` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `as`.

```
{% url 'event_detail' pk=event.id as event_music_url %}
{% if request.url == event_music_url %}
...
{% endif %}
```